# Spring can not load CSS

Tags: java, css, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Hello I have a little problem, when i'm starting my Spring boot web app, when i'm going to my localhost it cant load CSS.

I figured out that it's happening after adding "@ComponentScan" into Main class.

So i tried to remove it and then my whole controllers couldnt load ...

Meybe someone know solution to this problem. I've tried for about 3 days to do it and nothing helped. I'm putting a code below. meybe someone could figre it out for me.

MAIN.class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan({"com.estomed.Model"})
@EnableJpaRepositories({"com.estomed.Repository"})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.estomed"}, useDefaultFilters = true)

public class SynchronizesiteApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SynchronizesiteApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

WebConfig.class

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry){
    registry.addResourceHandler(
            "/webjars/**",
            "/img/**",
            "/css/**",
            "/js/**")
            .addResourceLocations(
                    "classpath:/static/webjars/",
                    "classpath:/static/img/",
                    "classpath:/static/css/",
                    "classpath:/static/js/");
    }
}
```

Header.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head th:fragment="header">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" th:src="@{~/images/logo2.png}" 
/>
<link th:text="@{~/css/bootstrap.min.css}" rel="stylesheet" />
<link th:text="@{~/style.css}" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body> <!-- Navigation -->
<!--class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top"-->

</body>
</html>
```

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHDAM.png)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OswNu.png)

I dont know what can i do more/I hope guys you'd help me

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `th:href` instead of `th:text` for link tag

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head th:fragment="header">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" th:href="@{/images/logo2.png}" 
    />
    <link th:href="@{/css/bootstrap.min.css}" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link th:href="@{/style.css}" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body> <!-- Navigation -->
    <!--class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top"-->

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I did that and still nothing, i even tried do something like :
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{~/css/style.css}" />

still doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
<link th:href="@{/bootstrap.min.css}" href="/bootstrap.min.css"  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  />
```